# Matlab: Extrinsics function on two checkerboards in one image

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I am using the [extrinsics](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extrinsics.html) function for a project that aims to determine distances of objects from the camera that have checkerboards attached to them. This is done for every frame in a video. My workflow is fairly simple:

Attach an asymmetric checkerboard to each object

Calibrate the camera using the Image Processing Toolbox on ~ 20 images

For each frame

```
while checkerboardsFound < numCheckerboards
 % Undistort the image
 data = undistortImage(data, cameraParams);
 % Get the checkerboard points in the frame
 [imagePoints, boardSize] = detectCheckerboardPoints(data);
 worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);
 % Get the rotation and translation
 [rot, trans] = extrinsics(imagePoints,worldPoints, cameraParams);

 % <Draw a black rectangle over the area where the checkerboard points are 
 % using the imagePoints matrix. This "hides" the checkerboard so we can
 % run the detectCheckerboardPoints(data) function again and find a different
 % one.>
 data = hideCheckerboard(data,...
        [imagePoints(1,:);...
        imagePoints(end,:)]);

 checkerboardsFound = checkerboardsFound + 1;
end;
```

**My problem is** that when I find, say, two particular checkerboards that are about 5cm in depth apart and look at the Z value of their respective translation vectors as returned by the *extrinsics* function, I expect to see a difference of about 50 units (5cm). However, I see a considerably greater difference - e.g. about 400 units (40cm). I am certain the square sizes for the checkerboards are correctly defined (5mm each). The frames come from a Samsung smart phone capturing in video mode (which applies magnification).

Could anyone please help determine what could be causing this discrepancy in the Z values? Is it too ambitious to use the *extrinsics* function in such a manner?

Comment: Have you checked the reprojection error of the calibration?

Comment: Upon calibration, I have removed any images with reprojection error over 1.5 pixels. My cameraParams' intrinsic estimation errors are as below:

    SkewError: 0
    FocalLengthError: [4.3099 4.3121]
    PrincipalPointError: [1.4831 2.2602]
    RadialDistortionError: [0.0026 0.0070]
    TangentialDistortionError: [0 0]

The mean of my extrinsic errors is [0.1750    0.2632    0.5233]